# on a mac with 12.04, how does one Iock icons to the launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, mac

My wife has an airbook.  How does one lock an icon to the launcher on a mac?  With a normal PC, it is easy, right click and "lock icon to launcher".  With mac, there is no right click, and the option and command buttons do not offer anything that is useful.  I am at  ncsailor62 (at the google mail site) gmail

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu in the Unity desktop, just drag the icon to the launcher, or right click and <kbd>Keep in Launcher</kbd>:
[image]
[image]

If this about something running Mac OS, this question does not really belong on this forum, but another like [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).

There is an article that may be of help [here](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/lock-dock-items-os-x-27016.html) anyway - apparently you can do pretty much the same thing in OS 10 - drag the icon of the file or folder to the dock, or right click on the application, then click <kbd>Options</kbd> and then <kbd>Keep in Dock</kbd>.

<sub>I can't verify the last bit, as I don't use Mac :-)</sub>